# Calling python script from java and collecting output line by line as written

Tags: java, python

I am currently working at integrating a Python (3.6.7) module in Java (8.0.191-oracle). If it matters, I'm working in IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu 18.04. The Python code is written as a batch job which prints verbose logging information to standard output using the print-function. The logging information currently contains time stamps in order to perform some light "post-hoc profiling" if the batch job starts getting slow. However, the logging should be performed by the calling Java program and be interleaved with logs from other parts of the system. Thus, I need to read the standard out (and err) of the Python process and redirect it to the standard out (and err) of the calling Java class.

To illustrate the situation, and the problem I have, I've written the following example (note that the timestamps here are just for development and to illustrate the problem). I have a Python file, `cr_test.py` which simply output 1000 timestamped lines of text with an interval of 0.01 seconds:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

for i in range(1, 1000):
    print(f"[PyTime: {datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]}]This is message no {i} from Python.")
    time.sleep(0.01)

print("Python test complete!")
```

When run, this produces:

```
[PyTime:13:42:10.486] This is message no 1 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.496] This is message no 2 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.507] This is message no 3 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.517] This is message no 4 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.527] This is message no 5 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.537] This is message no 6 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.548] This is message no 7 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.558] This is message no 8 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.568] This is message no 9 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.578] This is message no 10 from Python.
[PyTime:13:42:10.589] This is message no 11 from Python.
...
```

and so on.

I also have a Java class which simply uses ProcessBuilder to start the Python script and creates a thread listening to standard out (ignoring standard err in the example) of the Python process:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python3", "cr_test.py");
        try {
            final Process process = builder.start();
            Thread outThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()), 4096)) {

                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("[JavaTime:"+sdfDate.format(new Date())+"] "+line);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            outThread.start();

            int exitCode = -1;
            try {
                exitCode = process.waitFor();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This sort of works, with one important flaw: When the Python process is called from Java, the output from Python is not read line by line and printed as they arrive but rather there seems to be a delay or buffering producing the following sort of output (look at the Java vs Python time stamps, I have omitted most lines to simply illustrate where the "chunkiness" appears):

```
[JavaTime:13:43:28.629] [PyTime:13:43:27.163] This is message no 1 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.630] [PyTime:13:43:27.173] This is message no 2 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.631] [PyTime:13:43:27.183] This is message no 3 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.631] [PyTime:13:43:27.193] This is message no 4 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.631] [PyTime:13:43:27.203] This is message no 5 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.631] [PyTime:13:43:27.213] This is message no 6 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.631] [PyTime:13:43:27.223] This is message no 7 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.631] [PyTime:13:43:27.234] This is message no 8 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.632] [PyTime:13:43:27.244] This is message no 9 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.632] [PyTime:13:43:27.254] This is message no 10 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.632] [PyTime:13:43:27.264] This is message no 11 from Python.
 ...
[JavaTime:13:43:28.637] [PyTime:13:43:28.576] This is message no 139 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.637] [PyTime:13:43:28.586] This is message no 140 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.637] [PyTime:13:43:28.597] This is message no 141 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.637] [PyTime:13:43:28.607] This is message no 142 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:28.637] [PyTime:13:43:28.617] This is message no 143 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.092] [PyTime:13:43:28.627] This is message no 144 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.092] [PyTime:13:43:28.638] This is message no 145 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.092] [PyTime:13:43:28.648] This is message no 146 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.093] [PyTime:13:43:28.658] This is message no 147 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.093] [PyTime:13:43:28.668] This is message no 148 from Python.
...
[JavaTime:13:43:30.099] [PyTime:13:43:30.040] This is message no 281 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.099] [PyTime:13:43:30.050] This is message no 282 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.099] [PyTime:13:43:30.060] This is message no 283 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.099] [PyTime:13:43:30.071] This is message no 284 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:30.099] [PyTime:13:43:30.081] This is message no 285 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:31.556] [PyTime:13:43:30.091] This is message no 286 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:31.556] [PyTime:13:43:30.101] This is message no 287 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:31.556] [PyTime:13:43:30.112] This is message no 288 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:31.557] [PyTime:13:43:30.122] This is message no 289 from Python.
[JavaTime:13:43:31.557] [PyTime:13:43:30.132] This is message no 290 from Python.
...
```

That is, the output from Python is chunked and output, almost all at once, about every 1.5 seconds. If I change the intervals in Python to printing every 0.03 seconds I get basically the same chunks, only with longer intervals on the Java side, so it doesn't seem to be a timing issue but rather an issue with the amount of data. Well, sort of. Specifically it seems that somewhere around 142 lines at a time are released for printing by Java, but changing the length of the lines doesn't seem to have an effect.

I have tried flushing the buffer after each call to readLine, I have tried changing the size of the buffer. Neither seems to affect the problem.

Can anyone explain what is going on here and whether there is a way to get Java to print the lines from Python as they are printed? Or could someone at least direct me towards possible sources of the issue? Is it a Java issue? A Python issue? A VM issue? A system issue? This type of programming is not my area of expertise so I might have missed something obvious.

Comment: First thing I would do is run the python script directly, but redirect it to a file. In another terminal, tail the file, and see if the output appears line by line or in chunks.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic! Seems that the output from Python is redirected in chunks. That's not how it's printed if the output is not redirected. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Python has automatic buffering. Try `python -u`.